# Perspective Transformation

Tags: android, opencv, opengl-es, transform, perspective

I am given the X, Y, Z locations of 4 corners in a rectangle, and their X, Y locations on a picture. I would like to use these locations to find the camera's angle with the rectangle. For instance, if i am looking at a rectangle from the far right, it will appear like a trapezoid, with the right edge much longer than the left. Thus, I feel there should be an algorithm that can find the angles I am at relative to the rectangle.

I am coding on android, and I am using the opencv and opengl libraries. I have seen relevant algorithms in opencv, but they are not doing exactly what I need. Any helpful advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found that the method solvePnP in opencv will do exactly what I need it to do.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [3D projection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3D_projection) and try to derive reverse algorithms. Also, read [OpenGL FAQ](http://www.opengl.org/archives/resources/faq/technical/viewing.htm) as this is a frequently asked question.

Or, have a look at [the Viewing chapter](http://www.glprogramming.com/red/chapter03.html) of [the Red book](http://www.glprogramming.com/red/) ([link to Amazon](http://www.amazon.fr/Advanced-Graphics-Programming-Using-OpenGL/dp/1558606599)). Specifically, [the last heading](http://www.glprogramming.com/red/chapter03.html#name9) is what you have asked.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I have been looking into it, and I think i am going to use the cvPosit algorithm. The only problem is that I cannot find the methods in the android source code